# How to print (Cups, lpr, whatever...) in grayscale in a _generic_ way?

Tags: printing, cups, lpr

Problem:
E.g. Cups just offers options to manage colors. Unfortunately they are specific to the manufacturers model. I.e. xerox is using e.g. "XRXColor, BW", Dell "ColorModel, KGray" etc...

I am looking for a tool which offers a unified interface to the printserver to print grayscale.

Comment: Safe to assume that any options returned by `lpoptions -l` are out? Those appear to be only printer specific, but I'm checking.

Comment: Remember it should be generic. It should be scriptable. Hence I need a generic way.

Comment: What are you doing with all this lpr information you've been asking us about anyway?

Comment: Here's an idea I found: `lpr -o saturation=percent`. So if you want black/white you dial this down to 0, `lpr -o saturation=0`.

Comment: That options isn't listed as a printer opt. and I just tried it and our printer accepted the job. LMK if that satisfies your need and I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: `lp -o saturation=0` does not work in our setting. It just prints colored ...

Comment: OK, back to the drawing board then....

Answer (score 1):

You could print to PDF, then convert to grayscale (e.g. [via ImageMagick](https://superuser.com/questions/104656/convert-a-pdf-to-greyscale-on-the-command-line-in-floss) or [via GhostScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128656/how-to-convert-a-pdf-to-grayscale-from-command-line-avoiding-to-be-rasterized)), then print again.

[CUPS v1.3](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.3/options.html) had the `-o saturation=percent` (for non-OS-X image printing) and `-o blackplot` (for HP-GL/2 jobs) options, but they are no longer listed in 
[the current version (v1.7) of the docs](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.7/options.html). However, it seems you can [write a PPD driver](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.7/ppd-compiler.html) and specify either an appropriate `Resolution` or `ColorModel` directives. But I never did that, so I can't testify if it does what you need it to do.